# How to use ".ifnb" in Gnu Assembly? And how to accept a blank value as an argument for a ".macro" function in GAS?

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-64, gnu, att

I am trying to pass a blank value to a macro funtion in GNU Assembly on x64, this function is supposed to add three value togather or just two according to if the first argument is blank, e.g.,

```
.macro foo1 t0, t1, t2
  .ifnb t0
    add \t0, \t1
  .endif
    add \t1, \t2
.endm

foo2:
    foo1 , %rax, %rbx
    foo1 %rax, %rbx, %rcx
```

But when I complie the above code, the gcc said `expecting operand before ','; got nothing` because I call foo1 use the folloing format `foo1 , %rax, %rbx`.
So I am confused about how to use `.ifnb` pseudo-op, and how to pass a blank argument to a macro like foo1.

I tried to search in google, but I got few things about gnu assembly blank value. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/If.html
I also read GAS official docs but it also not mention how to use `.ifnb` and no blank argument example was given for `.macro`. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for `.ifnb` is as follows:

```
.macro foo1 t0, t1, t2
  .ifnb \t0             ; <------ Note the backslash preceding the `t0`
    add \t0, \t1
  .endif
    add \t1, \t2
.endm
```

You are getting a confusing error message pointing to the line of macro invocation, because it seem to be generated after the macro expansion to `add , %rax` but still refer to the line in the original code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that mistake! It works for me.